# UIButton inside a UIView subclass is not working, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I've seen similar SO questions, the most promising ones advised to set `.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` and `.bringSubview(toFront: subView)` however both these don't seem to work in my case (not sure if I am using it correctly). I am neither able to set the backgroundColor and border for the view.

Please advise where I am going wrong.

I would like to call a function on click of a editButton which is inside a subview.

This is what I get when I run the code:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
class ProfilePhotoView: UIView{

    var profileImage    =   UIImageView()
    var editButton      =   UIButton()
    var currentViewController   : UIViewController



    init(frame: CGRect, viewController : UIViewController){
        self.currentViewController = viewController

        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        setup()
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func setup(){

        profileImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profilePlaceHolder")
        editButton.setTitle("edit", for: .normal)
        editButton.setTitleColor(Colors.curieBlue, for: .normal)
        editButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editPhoto), for: .touchUpInside)

        profileImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  =   false

        editButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints     =   false

        self.addSubview(profileImage)
        self.addSubview(editButton)


        let viewsDict = [ "profileImage"    :   profileImage,
                          "editButton"       :   editButton
        ] as [String : Any]

        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[profileImage]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[profileImage]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))



        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[editButton]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[profileImage]-10-[editButton]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    }

    func editPhoto(){
        Utils.showSimpleAlertOnVC(targetVC: currentViewController, title: "Edit Button Clicked", message: "")
    }


}
```

ViewController using ProfilePhotoView

```
class ProfilePhotoViewVC: UIViewController {

    var profilePhotoView    :   ProfilePhotoView!
    //let imagePickerController   =   UIImagePickerController() // Initializing imagePicker
    //var imagePickerDelegate     =   ProfilePhotoDelegate()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let profilePhotoFrame               = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 800)
        profilePhotoView                    =   ProfilePhotoView(frame: profilePhotoFrame, viewController: self)
        profilePhotoView.isOpaque           = false
        profilePhotoView.backgroundColor    = Colors.lightGrey
        profilePhotoView.layer.borderWidth  = 1
        profilePhotoView.layer.borderColor  = Colors.iOSBlue.cgColor
        profilePhotoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints   =   false

        view.addSubview(profilePhotoView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: profilePhotoView)

        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let viewsDict = [ "profilePhotoView"    :   profilePhotoView] as [String : Any]

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[profilePhotoView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[profilePhotoView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: I had a hard time going through your code - probably my fault. Still, it's rather twisted. Not a straightforward MVC pattern. Why not just simply instantiate `ProfilePhotoView` inside your `ProfilePhotoViewVC`? What's the need for `self.currentViewController = viewController` in the init? With your code, I'd almost suggest taking a step back - as in doing "classic" MVC to start - and slowly adding this code in to see what broke things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you set this:

```
profilePhotoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

your `profilePhotoView`'s `width` and `height` get set to `0`, and you need to specify them with constraints.  Add `(==300)` and `(==800)` to your visual formats to set them:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[profilePhotoView(==300)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[profilePhotoView(==800)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
```

Also, consider using `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` to activate the constraints instead of adding them to the view.  *iOS* will add the constraints to the correct views for you.  Also, `options` has a default value of `[]`, so you can leave that off:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[profilePhotoView(==300)]",
    metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)
)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[profilePhotoView(==800)]",
    metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)
)
```